# disable checkbox based on value on jqx widgets grid cellsrenderer

Tags: jqxwidgets

disable checkbox based on value on jqx widgets grid cellsrenderer

here is my code:

```
var cellsrenderer = function (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) {
    var rowscount = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid("getdatainformation").rowscount;
    for (j = 0; j < rowscount; j++) {
        for (j = 0; j < rowscount; j++) {
            var data = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getrowdata', j);
            if (data.flag1 == '2') {
                if (columnfield == 'generatepc' && value == true)
                    //here need to disable the checkbox
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i'm unable to fix it, can you anyone provide solution or idea will be good to me

Comment: why you use the same loop twice ? => `for (j = 0; j < rowscount; j++)`

Comment: btw, what checkbox do you used ? jqxCheckBox ? if yes, then you can make it disabled with this one `$('#jqxCheckBox').jqxCheckBox({ disabled:true }); `